# operator & cannot be applied to operands of type bool and byte in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to use string and byte in the same condition but getting an error

> operator & cannot be applied to operands of type bool and byte

```
        string m = "";
        string mi= "";
        byte Active = 0;
        
        if ((m== mi) & Active)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Try `if ((m== mi) & Active == 0)...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unary operator `&` can be performed over a `boolean`.
In your case the left operand is a `boolean` , while the right operand needs to be an expression that returns also a `boolean`:

```
if( (m==mi) & expression_that_returns_boolean ){
}
```

`System.byte` is a keyword that is used to declare a variable which can store an unsigned value range from 0 to 255.

Thus your `if` statement effectively becomes :

`if (boolean & byte )`

> operator & cannot be applied to operands of type bool and byte

Therefore the right operand of  your `&` operator should be a expression whose result is a `boolean`

In your case you should create an expression that applied over your `byte` returns a `boolean`:

```
byte Active=0;
if( (m==mi) & expression(Active) )
```

The expression could be :
`Active==[some_integer]`

Resulting:
`if( (m==mi) & Active==0 )`